# Training different ML models using Caret

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, gbm

I am trying to train a couple of ML models using the trainControl and train functions in Caret but I am always getting the same error which just says:

Error: Stopping

without giving any more details.

The problem is the same for gbm and ranger, so I am wondering if it has something to do with a conflict of the packages I am also using in my code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lattice)
library(caret)
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)
library(Matrix)
library(glmnet)
library(iterators)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel) # parallel processing.
registerDoParallel(cores=16)
library(randomForest)
library(gbm)
library(ranger)
library(data.table)
library(smooth)

    data<- data.frame(A=seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), by=1, len=100),B=as.numeric(runif(100, 50, 150)),C=as.numeric(runif(100, 50, 150)))

  # define data sets
    data_training<-data[1:60,]
    data_test<-data[(60+1):nrow(data),]

  # creating sampling seeds
  set.seed(123)

  n=nrow(data_training)
  tuneLength.num <- 5

  seeds <- vector(mode = "list", length = n) # creates an empty vector containing lists
  for(i in 1:(n-1)){ # choose tuneLength.num random samples from 1 to 1000
    seeds[[i]] <- sample.int(1000, tuneLength.num) 
  }

  # For the last model:
  seeds[[n]] <- sample.int(1000, 10)

  # Define TimeControl for training and fitting:
  trainingTimeControl <- trainControl(method = "timeslice",
                                      initialWindow = 25,
                                      horizon = 1,
                                      fixedWindow = TRUE,
                                      returnResamp="all",
                                      allowParallel = TRUE,
                                      seeds = seeds,
                                      savePredictions = TRUE)

  gbm.mod<- caret::train(B ~.- A,
                             data = data_training,
                             method = "gbm",
                             distribution = "gaussian",
                             trControl = trainingTimeControl,
                             tuneLength=tuneLength.num, 
                             metric="RMSE")
```

EDIT: The following code works just fine:

```
gbm<-gbm(formula = B ~  . - A, 
                  distribution = "gaussian",
                  data = data_training,
                  keep.data = TRUE)
```

It would be great if anyone has an idea what is going on here. The code is working fine with svmRadial.

Comment: Does a single `gbm` without `caret` cross-validation work when all the other stuff is loaded? And how long before the error happens?

Comment: Yes it does - see edit above. The error appears instantly.

Comment: I ran this and got warnings with the error. You can access these by typing `warnings()`

Comment: `1: model fit failed for Training25: shrinkage=0.1, interaction.depth=1, n.minobsinnode=10, n.trees=250 Error in (function (x, y, offset = NULL, misc = NULL, distribution = "bernoulli", The data set is too small or the subsampling rate is too large: nTrain * bag.fraction <= n.minobsinnode`

Comment: So ... the folds of the cross validation aren't being adequately fit by the `GBM` and GBM won't return a garbage fit on too little data. On the other hand ... SVM.has no such qualms.